# About jndi database connection

Tags: java

What is the exact purpose of jndi.Why i need to depends on server for my database connection.I can get the same database connection in normal ojdbc itself.
please help me with that.
Thanks n advance

Comment: JNDI is just a set of interfaces. All you're doing is using a standard API instead of a vendor-specific one. You're still calling the vendor classes directly, for the most part. The cost is practically zero. Why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some pointers why i personally prefer JNDI over harcoded configurations in code.

- Application can work with any database since it does not need to
  bundle the driver.
- Multiple applications running on server can use the same connection
  pool which might be better use of resources.
- This allows container to perform XA transactions in case other
  databases are used.